# is casesensitive important for appId

Tags: java, api, oauth-2.0

I am generate the uniq id for my apps called appId, this is the code I am using right now:

```
import java.util.UUID;

public class AppStarter {

    private final static String[] chars = new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",
            "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
            "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
            "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
            "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
            "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("shortId："+getAppId());
    }
    
    public static String getAppId() {
        StringBuffer shortBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            String str = uuid.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
            shortBuffer.append(chars[x % 0x3E]);
        }
        return shortBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

the generate appId like this `18TG4EiPQab9N8x5`, is it matter for the case sensitive with appId, should I use lower case for the appId? or lower case and upper case make no difference?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what do you mean by appId, if it's in the terminologies of oauth2 i think you mean client_id, if it's that, the client_id dont matter if it's a string or number, there is no rule for the client_id because it is supposed to be used in the public front unlike client_secret

Comment: I think case sensitivity is not mandatory in this type of case, but it is the convention developers follow. So, case sensitive name is good.

Comment: why I found developer appId or client id all make lower case. like this `1234567890-abc123def456.apps.googleusercontent.com` @GAOUL is that means we should consider the lower case is better for us in the furture?

Comment: for a better user experience, yes you can use the lower case, all big company google, facebook or others use lawer