# should I consider the case sensitive when design the rest api url

Tags: api, rest, http

Now I am design a rest api, what makes me confusing is that the url case sensitive, for example, the `/currentUser`, I read some api design like google:

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/exchangeAuthCode
```

the named with camel case, and youtube:

```
https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/log_event?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8
```

the named snake case, and stackoverflow:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71447875/is-casesensitive-important-for-appid
```

the named with a `-`. which is better? which one should I choose? or both are good, there is no need to consider the url case sensitive?

Comment: Use the style you prefere most. I'd avoid a dash-styled names coz they are inconvenient - double-click or a ctrl+shift+arrow will not select the whole term. And about case sensitivity, yes such the things should be case sensitive, just coz case insensitivity requires additional code doing nothing really useful.

Comment: Doesn't matter, just be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to RFC 3986, URLs: `/resourcename` and `/resourceName`
are different. BUT: The general convention nowadays is to treat all URLs uniformly, regardless of character size.

Most REST APIs use hyphenated notation: `/resource-name`
Google is somewhat schizophrenic because it recommends something different [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/url-structure?hl=en&visit_id=637831147683768290-955108535&rd=1).

I recommend being case insensitive, using hyphens, and being consistent throughout the API.